# Autowired Jersey ContainerRequestContext into Spring bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jersey, inversion-of-control, hk2

I have a Jersey+Spring project and I would like to retrieve some data from `ContainerRequestContext` without passing the `ContainerRequestContext` instance all the way from the controller to the bottom layer spring service. So is there any way that I can inject/autowired `ContainerRequestContext` into a Spring bean?

Or any other more proper solutions which meet the requirement are welcome.

Comment: Accessing it in a service is a bad thing imho, as that ties your service layer to the web. You should have your controller prepare something for the service (bottom layer) and not have the layer below the web depend on the web (or even worse in this case imho) the infrastructure layer.

Comment: @M.Deinum totally agree with the decoupling the web layer and service layer. I had a solution is to store request data in `InheritableThreadLocal` and retrieve it in other layers. However this solution would failed if my application is using thread pool. I think this is the best solution so far t to me to avoid adding more parameters to every service method in my project

Comment: Why not simply pass it to a method? And why would it fail if you use a thread pool (which is how servlet containers work!). If you don't do any async processing you should be ok, but still why not simply pass it to the method instead of relying on a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: yep you are right, thread pool is for async processing.
And I am trying to avoid adding more parameters to every service method in my project.

Comment: Are you using the hk2-bridge (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b24/spring-bridge.html).  If so then you can add a service to the Jersey hk2 ServiceLocator at any time and it should become available to be injected from Spring as well